# STS2.6 grails error : unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create

Tags: grails, jetty, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

grails project,
work fine at SpringSource Tool Suite 2.5.1.RELEASE
got problem at SpringSource Tool Suite 2.6.0 RELEASE

error message:
    Running Grails application..
    2011-03-29 10:29:45,140 [main] ERROR http11.Http11Protocol  - Error initializing endpoint
    java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create

Comment: What version of Grails are you using and does this work on the command line?

Comment: had try 1.3.6 and 1.3.7.  cant work at sst, but work on command line. i wonder if it's sts grails plugin's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could possibly be a problem with the Java executable that you are using.  See this thread:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=106504&highlight=Unrecognized+Windows+Sockets+error

The poster worked around the problem by adding the following line to the buildConfig.groovy file:

```
grails.server.port.http=9080
```

If this doesn't work for you, I'd recommend following up on the STS forum:

http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=32

(you can even post to the thread above)

Comment: Please post to the thread above, one of our engineers is actively working on this problem.  Have you tried the latest dev build?